# windows azure script services add message to queue

Tags: mobile, azure

I'm using Windows Azure Mobile services to upload pictures from a mobile app. The mobile script services accepts the file, saves it's name to the database.
What I'm trying to do is to be able to add a message to a queue which will resize the uploaded image. 
Do Script services supports calling queues from within or I have to make my app do that call?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to send a message to the queue:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var queueService = azure.createQueueService("myaccount", "mykey");    
queueService.createQueueIfNotExists("myqueuename", function(error){ });
queueService.createMessage("myqueuename", "contentOfTheMessage", function(error){});
```

Comment: Where is the MSDN documentation for these azure script apis?